# How to send all requests from localhost through another server which has the access to endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy

I have a `Spring Boot 2` project, that I cannot test locally. To test I use another server. So I deploy here my project and I can test it. But it's so uncomfortable.

I'm interested in how to redirect my request to that server to be able work locally.

[LOCALHOST] -> [SERVER] -> [ENDPOINT]

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @cy3er yes, I have

Comment: Is local instance similar to application running over [SERVER], or [SERVER] is just a middleware. In case it is similar connect local to remote provided remote debugging is enabled.

Comment: in that case you can create an [ssh tunnel with port forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) then the endpoint will be available on your localhost.